# Date & time conversion format in Snowflake DB

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I convert the time from a timestamp column to 12 hour format in Snowflake? My hours are still in 24 hour format.

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM') AS CONVERTED;`

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM62A.png)

I have tried this query so far. I expected my CONVERTED column to say 05/15/2023 7:05 PM. I have also been looking through the Snowflake documentation site, but I have not found how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below SQL -

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM') AS CONVERTED;
```

By default `HH:MI` means  `HH24:MI`. If you want AM/PM, you need to specify `HH12:MI`. And you should never use `HH:MI AM` because it doesnt make any sense.

[docs here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime)